# Getting url params into controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my website I load a _form made by rails scaffold onto my page, which is under my home_controller.

It only has one text input box for *name*, but the table im inputting this entry into also requires a bigint value, called course_id.

I pass this course_id value into that page by passing it as a url param.

then in my mod_controller i have `@mod.course_id = Course.find(params[:course_id]).id`
in my def create function.

any suggestions to help this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want to do this in your Model instead of your Controller? (I am not sure I understand your question though)